# TextureView solves flickering?

Tags: android, page-curl

I have a problem with GLSurfaceView subclass of SurfaceView as described [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2011/11/android-40-graphics-and-animations.html)

I´m using SlidingMenu so when my CurlView that extends of GLSurfaceView is moved appears a flickering effect as describes [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qSBuFqMliJM&feature=youtu.be).

How can i solve it?

Comment: I also have textureview flickering issue when playing video